# Strange behavior on Router Outlet in Angular 10

Tags: angular

In default AppModule that is like a prefix template i have this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in my **AppRoutingModule** I have this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./layout/layout.module').then((m) => m.LayoutModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And in my **LayoutModule** I have this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BottomComponent } from './bottom/bottom.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './content/content.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { LayoutRoutingModule } from './layout-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LayoutComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BottomComponent,
    ContentComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    LayoutRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: []

})

export class LayoutModule { }
```

And here is my **LayoutRoutingModule**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../pages/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule {}
```

But in my **app.component.html** I have only a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and I getting this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlet' of undefined**

What I'm doing wrong? It is Angular 10.

Comment: Looks like you are not using your AppRoutingModule anywhere.

Comment: Can you add the LayoutRoutingModule to your post as well

Comment: Hi @MuhammadKamran I'm using in AppModule do you see there? And I update my answer look again, Thank you all.

Comment: How does the routing for HomeModule look like?

Comment: can you make a stackblitz ? https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues in only one , you need to use new one for your `LayoutRoutingModule`. I'm not sure, please update question with `LayoutModule` and `LayoutComponent` code

Btw,  this is not correct way to implement layout component, always layout component declared in root routing module (`app-routing.module`), like:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: LayoutComponent,
  children: {
    {
       path: '',
       redirectTo: 'home',
       pathMatch: 'full,
    },
    {
       path: 'home',
       loadChildren: () => import('../pages/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
    },
    {
      ...
    }  
  }
}
```